# Symfony2 selective clear cache

Tags: symfony, caching

Is there a way to selective remove some cache sites from http_cache in symfony2?
Is it possible, to skip clearing the http_cache when you call cache:clear --env=prod?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it manually. But with the command console is not possible.